# how to redirect all URLs to a different URL?

Tags: .htaccess

e.g

I have a urls like this, domain/buy-now/product title/productid

```
http://www.mydomain.com/buy-now/this-is-the-product-one/order/1234
```

Considering an online shop contains alot of products with different product title and product ID right?
how am I going to redirect "all URLs from that format", into "this new URL" via htaccess ?

```
http://www.mydomain.com/buy-now/order/this-is-the-product/1234
```

the difference is, the word "order" got transferred beside the "buy-now"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^buy-now/([^/]+)/order/([0-9]+)$ /buy-now/order/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

You can remove the `=301` from the square brackets if you don't want a permanent redirect. If you'd rather use an htaccess file in the `/buy-now` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /buy-now/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/order/([0-9]+)$ order/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This results in an infinite loop.

Comment: i'm having an error with that `The requested URL /test/buy-now/11amproduct/order/1605 was not found on this server.`  ..is it because the order doesn't really exist among the directories ?

Comment: @sasori it's because you have a `/test/` in the URL